# Как работает request.body?

Tags: python, django

Есть такой проект на github - [django-proxy](https://github.com/mjumbewu/django-proxy/blob/master/proxy/views.py).
Он использует библиотеку requests.
По сути в представлении происходит трансляция заголовков, метода запроса и его тела в requests. 
Суть вопроса в следующем:
Если тело запроса будет очень большим (например, это put запрос очень большого,  в несколько гигабайт файла) - как поведёт себя код:

```
requests_args['data'] = request.body # mjumbewu/django-proxy/views.py #27
response = requests.request(request.method, url, **requests_args) #views.py #45
```

Беспокоит прежде всего как эти данные будут переданы между django request.body и requsets.request - будут ли они переданы как stream, либо сохранены в некоторый временный файл на диске, или (худший из вариантов) будут закачены в ОЗУ, затем в requests?
Можно ли управлять политикой передачи в данном случае? 
Идеальный вариант - stream. Чуть хуже - через временный файл. ОЗУ вообще не рассматриваем. 
Вопрос именно в необходимости "переделывания" данного кода в контексте наличия запросов с большим объемом данных.

Comment: `request.body` это байтовая строка, так что читается целиком в память (лениво, при первом обращении к `request.body`). Теоретически можно читать постепенно через `request.read(сколько байт прочитать)`, но это разумеется нужно сам django-proxy переделывать

Comment: Если без изменений кода - можно, конечно, манкипатчить `requests.request(request.method, url, stream=True, **requests_args)` и подменить `HttpResponse` `StreamingHttpResponse`'ом, но без тестов (а их там вообще нет) такой костыль в прод пускать нельзя.

Comment: Там, кстати, даже есть [PR, предлагающий это](https://github.com/mjumbewu/django-proxy/pull/8) - можешь потестить локально, `pip install git+https://github.com/randoms/django-proxy`

Comment: Удалось сделать через chunk - read. ОЗУ не сжирается. Но почему то файл блокируется до полной загрузки на сервер, после чего функция его чтения начинает работу.

Comment: stream = True помогло. Ответ ниже.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему.

```
def chunk_req(file, block_size=1024, chunks=-1):
    while chunks:
        data = file.read(block_size)
        if not data:
            break
        yield data
        chunks -= 1


def proxy_files(request):
    for filename, file in request.FILES.items():
        upload_url = 'http://domain.com/upload'
        requests.put(upload_url, data=chunk_req(file), stream = True)
    return HttpResponse('OK')
```